# How to extract string in Eval function in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

How to extract string in Eval function in c#?

```
  Eval("FileName").toString
```

I want display extension of file in grid view.

Comment: Just make a string variable that you can pass into eval?

Comment: Please show me how!!!

Comment: please post more of your code

Comment: `string s = "FileName"; Eval(s)` surely you've done this somewhere, what have you tried/researched?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Path.Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method:-

```
Text='<%# Path.GetExtension((string)(Eval("FileName"))) %>'
```

Make sure, you import `System.IO` namespace either in web.config file or in your mark-up page like this:-

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
```

If `Eval("FileName")` contains `C:\Test\Hello.txt`, then it will return `.txt`